# iPad force connection to WiFi WITHOUT Internet

Tags: ios, ipad, networking

I'm working on an embedded device that will communicate with (WiFi-only) iPads over WiFi.  However, these devices are not connected to the internet.  They are simply connecting to a specific port, which is constantly relaying certain information.  The iPad connects to the Access Point, receives an IP Address from DHCP, and can now reach the desired

What I'm seeing is frequent disconnects, or interruptions in the connection.

My suspicion is that iPad's inability to connect to `captive.apple.com/library/test/success.html` is causing it to either re-scan for WiFi networks or in some other way momentarily disrupt the connection.

Is there a way to disable this behavior, or ensure that an iPad remains connected to the intended WiFi, even in the absence of an Internet connection?  Either through a setting on the iPad, or a configuration setting on the embedded router/Access Point?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.

Comment: That's probably fair.  My first draft of this question had increased emphasis on the NSStreamEvent and the NSError code, but I currently suspect the connection interruption is happening at a level below my code's reach.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind breaking backwards compatibility with older iOS devices (iOS 3, for example), I'm told (by someone in DTS, IIRC) that you can send a DHCP advertisement without a router advertisement field, and iOS will do the right thing.  I have not tried this personally, though.

You might also try using the CaptiveNetwork framework (deprecated in iOS 9 with no replacement) to claim control over the SSID, and the just never report success or failure.  I'm not sure if that would work or not, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  I'd definitely be more comfortable being incompatible with older devices rather than newer ones.